# Send ether from one wallet to another with solidity smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, transfer, wallet

I want to send ether from one walet to another…what technique to use and what is the safest method to do so?
wallet A(msg.sender)=10ether
wallet B=10ether
with the help of smart contract send 'x' ether from A to B.

I tried
where 'x' is the varaible ether at different times.
=>payable().transfer(msg.value);
here i am able to send ether in remix ide where i can provide the msg.value...i want to implement that it is able to change msg.value according to the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove ether from someone's wallet on their behalf.

You can do something like this with ERC20 tokens, which have an `approve` functionality, but there is no API for this with native Ether.

To send ether out of a wallet, the owner of the wallet must sign a transaction specifying they want to send a certain amount of ether to a certain address.

Now, you can sign a transaction, and have someone else broadcast it. This is called relaying. But once you sign a transaction that sends ether from your wallet, you can basically consider the ether gone.

If you need to conditionally take ether from a user, having the user stake the ether in an escrow contract may make more sense.

Comment: So basically what i am doing is dispersing all the collected assets in my contract. I am successfully able to disperse the tokens but i am not able to do it for the native ether. How can i have a make the user sign a transaction to give away ether from his wallet to another wallet…any source you have on this?

Comment: Our contract doesn’t contains any tokens or ether just to clarify